# Profile2: How to understand if user has not an associated profile?

Tags: 7, users

I'm not able to understand what is the code I should use to verify if user has (or not) a profile (made by profile2 module) associated.

I use `profile2_load_by_user($uid, "my-profile-name")` and it always returns me a "Profile" object... also for users that has not that profile (for example users listed in `/admin/people/noprofile`).

I know I can test if some mandatory field is currently filled, but do you know what is the "formally correct" way to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing `profile2_load_by_user` and profile object is showing, then its profile object has been created. If Profile object has not been created for a user, then its profile object will be empty, means its pid has still not been created.

You can check for the same, in your database, inside profile table.

Comment: Yes, you're rigth: there is a corresponding row inside profile table (with the same pid/uid of the Profile object returned by profile2_load_by_user)... but I can't figure why /admin/people/noprofile page (labelled as "Sites users without profile") reports me that user.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment (URL I reported was a view that filters on a mandatory field). Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check what return

```
$profiles = profile2_load_multiple(FALSE, array('uid' => $uid));

or direct query
$result = db_select('profile', 'p')
      ->fields('p', array('type', 'pid'))
      ->condition('uid', $uid)
      ->execute()
```

Comment: I made a query to DB, but I think it is the same... as I wrote as comment in the other answer: a profile exists in that row, but... then... why that user is reported as "Sites users without profile" in /admin/people/noprofile page?

Comment: How did you get that page? I don't see code related to /admin/people/noprofile in Profile 2 module

Comment: Me too... and there is no any track of the string "noprofile" inside aliases on in my drupal installation folder... I'm investigating to understand what's happening, but I suppose it can be a kind of configuration made by old developers of the platform. I will update you. Thank you for now.

Comment: Yes, it was as I supposed... it was a specific view that filters on mandatory fields. BTW sorry, but I'll choose the other answer as accepted, just because it explains in the main "box" what is the core of my question, and can be better for future readers. +1 and thank you for your support.